# What is the visual intuition behind solving equations with linear algebra ? (row picture vs column picture)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm visiting [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=2&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare) on linear algebra, where the teacher propose that you can see a set of equations in row or column picture.

The first way, the usual way, is to think of it as rows:

```
2x-y = 0
-x+2y = 3
```

You can plot a line on a graph for the first equation, which is all the possible answers for this equation. Then plot a second line for the second equation. Where lines meet is the point where the answer is valid for both equation, giving us a solution.

The second way of thinking about it is via the [column picture](https://youtu.be/ZK3O402wf1c?t=717)

```
x [2 -1]' + y [-1 2]' = [0 3]'
```

You then can draw the first vector, the second vector and find how much of them arrive at the answer vector.

However I can't wrap my head around why that works. The main thing that is bugging me is that he made a vector of the two x's and another with the two y's and when drawing those the first vector (with two x's), he draws it on a x, y plane, with x and y components. I don't see how the x suddenly is y, and how that relates to the first picture (row picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, you need to give other names to the coordinates in the plane where you're drawing, say $(u,v)$ instead of $(x,y)$. That is, you're drawing the vectors $(u,v)=(2,1)$, $(u,v)=(-1,2)$ and $(u,v)=(0,3)$ in the $uv$-plane (feel free to write them as column vectors if you like, but I was too lazy to do that here), and then you ask how many steps you need to go along the first vector ($x$ steps) and along the second vector ($y$ steps) in order to obtain the third vector.

Comment: I see, there is no relation between the two planes in the two pictures. If there was only one equation the 2 vectors would be in 1D giving a result in 1D, which gives an infinite number of possibilities. The second dimension is actually the second equation, so it's kinda the same as in the row picture. Where when adding that second dimension you are left with one only answer. I think I get the intuition behind it, I guess the fact that he used x,y for the column picture confused me.